# URL RewriteRule .htaccess for more SEO friendly shape

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I have URLs like 
`book.php?id=23` `product.php?id=23` etc..
I want them to be something like

```
book/id/title
```

my current .htaccess is this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^book/([0-9]+)\-([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ book.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

but it's not working properly, 
it's directing to book.php page despite of problems in page, I can't Get the Id parameter using `$_GET` , any help is appreciated 
here's my url http://www.gamzesart.com/book.php?id=2

Comment: I have place an answer below. Did you see my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I had this problem the other week, it turned out it was because the url reference was the same as the name as the php file I was calling, i.e:

```
RewriteRule ^book/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ book.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Just as a test, change your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^books/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ book.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

and try calling the URL as books/23 instead.

Comment: Cool. The curious thing is that every online tutorial I've ever seen uses examples like ^product and product.php, or ^category and category.php so I don't know why this should be. Maybe someone else can shed some light on this?

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely strange issue. 
the same happened with me too.

Comment: I highly suspect it depends on whether the server is set up to run extensionless PHP or not, but don't take my word for it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656432/strange-url-rewriterule-htaccess-issue-needs-explaination 
I opened a question

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
+FollowSymLinks   # This is based on the comment of PeteR bellow in comments
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^book/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ book.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

That works for me.

In my local PC I have try to access the URL : http://www.localSite.dch/book/12/nikos

and in my book.php file I have the following code:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
print_r($_REQUEST);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The result is this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 12
)
```

Comment: thanks, but didn't work, I edited my question and added the real link, you can try to check the URL if you want, I modified .htaccess to be like yours. no hope :\

Comment: In your htaccess file, do you have any other rules before this one ?

Comment: is your mod_rewrite enebled ?

Comment: Try adding Options +FollowSymLinks to the top of the .htaccess file.

Comment: well, I tried without Options +FollowSymLinks, it didn't work, it was the same bringing the page book.php but with no $_REQUEST data.
with Options +FollowSymLinks I got 500 error