# Strange URL RewriteRule .htaccess Issue needs explaination

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have URLs like `book.php?id=23` and using htaccess to make them `book/id/title` 
I tried this

```
RewriteRule ^book/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ book.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

but it didn't work, it was forwarding to `books.php` but no `$_REQUEST` data
 it turned out it was because the url reference was the same as the name as the php file I was calling with help from the community to work around this worked

```
RewriteRule ^books/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ book.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

this is my current working .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^kitap/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ book.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^yyin/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ yayin.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^proje/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ project.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

[PeteR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2710715/peter):

> every online tutorial I've ever seen uses examples like ^product and
>   product.php, or ^category and category.php so I don't know why this
>   should be. Maybe someone else can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

I started messing with this after our small discussion on your original question and I'm starting to think it depends on the server configuration and whether or not it will run extensionless scripts.

My dev server, for example, will run extensionless scripts, i.e. typing /xyz will display xyz.php

A rewrite rule of

```
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

does not work, however

```
RewriteRule ^categories/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

does work.

On my hosting server, which does not support extentionless scripts, www.mydomain.com/xyz will give me a 404 error, but:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

works as expected.

I can only assume that when the server supports extensionless scripts then the rewrite rule is ignored if the alias is identical to the script name.

Comment: I worked around with that on my server too, my server does support extentionless scripts, Coincidence? think not. 
same case too, my other hosting which does't support extentionless scripts works out fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have `MultiViews` on which conflicts with rewrite rules.

**Fulle .htaccess:** (Goes in DOCUMENT_ROOT directory)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^kitap/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ book.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^yyin/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ yayin.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^proje/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ project.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^books/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ book.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I haven't even provided you any rule so certainly redirect loop is being caused by existing rules/code. If you post your full .htaccess in your question I can investigate and suggest a fix.

Comment: Can you post your existing .htaccess in your question.

Comment: see updated code with your full .htaccess. Make sure .htaccess and book.php are both at the root level of your site and **there is no other .htaccess anywhere in your system**