# How to cut a parameter without value via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to cut the parameter, leaving just its value using htaccess. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It should look like this:

localhost/?url=abc --> localhost/abc

Please help :)

Comment: This is probably the most attempted change to the querystring. A duckduck would give you thousands of examples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL RewriteRule .htaccess for more SEO friendly shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654092/url-rewriterule-htaccess-for-more-seo-friendly-shape)

Comment: @RiggsFolly i tried: `RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
` and `RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
` and not working :/

Comment: Then put that in your question